# Update Database Table based on Datatable Cells Value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable and in DataTable there are two Columns "BATCH NUM" and "QTY".
And on other hand i have Table named Invoice in Database. So what i want to do is that to Update Value of "QTY" in INVOICE Table where 'BATCH NUM' matches in INVOICE Table.

---

### BatchNum | QTY

1------------------|-----10

2------------------|-----20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{


public static void Main()
{
    var dt = CreateDataTable();

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        UpdateTable(Convert.ToInt32(row["BatchNum"]), Convert.ToInt32(row["QTY"]));     
    }

}

public static void UpdateTable(int batchNum, int qty)
{
    string sql = "update invoice set qty = "+qty+" where batchnum = " + batchNum ;
    Console.WriteLine(sql);
}


public static DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BatchNum"));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("QTY"));

    var row1 = dt.NewRow();
    var row2 = dt.NewRow();

    row1["BatchNum"] = 1;
    row1["QTY"] = 10;
    row2["BatchNum"] = 2;
    row2["QTY"] = 20;

    dt.Rows.Add(row1);
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);

    return dt;
}
```

}